# What are the advantages of having badges?

Tags: discussion, badges

There's a fair amount of information available on badges (what they are, how to earn them, etc.), but actually surprisingly little information about what the actual point of having badges is in the first place.

I am aware that, if you run for moderator, you're expected/required to have certain badges. Also, gold badges for specific tags can give you dupe-marking privileges. Other than that, are there concrete advantages to having badges? Or are they mostly ways to measure "good citizenship" in a way that's analogous to how reputation measures the quality of your posts?

Also, I've heard the argument that they encourage participation in the site because people try to earn badges. Is this true (i.e. Do people actually consciously try to earn badges)? Is there any evidence for or against that hypothesis?

Comment: *"They encourage participation in the site because people try to earn badges. Is this true?"* --> Well, it's kind of a collection, as you could collect stamps or coins. Personally, I'm happy when I get a new gold badge... ;p

Comment: You may want to read on [Gamification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification)

Comment: A common error made by ruthlessly logical thinkers is to either ignore, or fail to understand, how the minds of other people operate.  There is often great difficulty in developing an appreciation for the, often considerable, differences in the primary driving forces of human behaviour as experienced by a significant majority of other people.  I suppose the real irony is that the people who tend to study Psychology are usually the people who least need to.  If you could only put the psych students in a programming course and the programming students in a psych course...

Comment: I'm surprised on such question like this, I thought such questions have already existed.

Comment: @Yawz I would've assumed so too, but apparently not - that's one of the reasons I asked.

Comment: Badges? We don't need no stinking badges.

Comment: It’s the same advantage you get when earning more reputation than 20k.

Comment: I read the question title as _"badgers"_. How disappointing...

Comment: @Holger More downvotes on answers without losing your privileges?

Comment: @Aaroninus: maybe I should have said “the same as earning more reputation than 40k”. I didn’t think about the risk of loosing privileges when downvoting, usually, I get back the points anyway, once the answer has been deleted (or improved, so I have no reason for the downvote anymore, to stay optimistic).

Comment: [Related](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TFwprS_L6tg): *[Stack Overflow Badge Feedback](https://stackoverflow.blog/2008/07/stack-overflow-badge-feedbac/)*

Comment: WOW ! keiwan.. I never knew

Comment: I have to actively try to ignore the badges, I can be OCD on trying to complete them and get the next recommended badge and it becomes quite exhausting LOLOLOLOL

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Badges, by and large, pat you as a user on the back for using a specific site feature.  Bronze badges are more intended as introductory and are there to show you the new features, whereas silver and gold are more of the actual getting-involved-in-the-community kind of badges.

As a user, it's impossible *not* to gain badges unless you're simply not active on the site.  Also, the gold badges you mention are tag badges, which are a bit special unto themselves; they're the only badge that can be *lost* due to point fluctuations in that tag.

I wouldn't think there's an "advantage" to having a lot of badges; if you do have them, then that means you participate quite heavily on the site.  Reputation and past activity in moderator-like activities factor heavier into whether or not a user would make a suitable diamond moderator or not, at least in my opinion.

Comment: They do make a lot of sense for moderators I think. I think tag badges are sensible too because if you have one it lends more credibility to your answers (at least for that particular tag) because it's evidence of expertise.

Comment: You have enough badges to make me believe you

Comment: Oh. . Thanks for the info.

Comment: A tag gold badge gives you a [Dupehammer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/dupehammer/info).

Comment: @LURD I believe this is what EJoshuaS means by advantages. Perhaps  more accurate terms may include benefits or responsibilities or powers?

Comment: "at least in my opinion" It isn't just a matter of opinion. You can't run for moderator without having certain badges.

Comment: @matt: That's unique to Stack Overflow.  To my knowledge, other sites [don't have a badge requirement](http://anime.stackexchange.com/election/2) at all.

Comment: @Makoto Didn't know that, thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Makoto's answer summed up the high-level explanation perfectly. I wanted to add some color to:

> Is this true (i.e. Do people actually consciously try to earn badges)? Is there any evidence for or against that hypothesis?

It's an anecdote with a sample size of 1, so take it with a grain of salt, but I absolutely have increased my participation on the site in the past to gain specific badges. Even though I know it's a gamification trick, it still works on me. :)

Comment: I think there's plenty of data in the hands of the dev and community team that shows users increased activity and engagement when badges get involved. Perhaps a CM will see this post and provide some data.

Comment: I don't agree. Badges are fun in their way, but there is only one badge that I have ever consciously striven for, and even then I knew it was pointless.

Comment: @matt And yet you strove for it...

Answer (score 10):

The purpose of badges is similar to [scout badges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scout_badge):

1. to encourage positive behaviors on the site. Not everything can be rewarded by reputation alone.
2. to identify proficiency: some badges are really hard to get and having them is meaningful for potential moderator candidates.
3. to grant extra powers: a gold badge in a tag makes your duplicate close votes effective directly, without the need for more votes for example.

Comment: I've moved this answer from the dupe to this canonical question, as I feel it provides value over the other answers posted.

Answer (score 4):

Stack Overflow's badge system follows the well known trend of [Gamification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification), defined as "the application of game-design elements and game principles in non-game contexts".

**In Short:** People like earning achievements because it provides a clear set of goals to aim for, then gives positive feedback when those goals are accomplished. If you look at [Stack Overflow's badge list](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges), you can see that many of them serve as reasonable goals for new users to reach.

It's a positive feedback loop. A user earns a badge for good behavior, encouraging them to continue that behavior, which leads to earning more badges, which hopefully leads to more good behavior.

---

#### Further reading:

- Psychology of Games: [Why Do Achievements, Trophies, and Badges Work?](http://www.psychologyofgames.com/2016/07/why-do-achievements-trophies-and-badges-work/)
- Extra Credits: [Gamification - How the Principles of Play Apply to Real Life](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1dLK9MW-9sY)
- Wikipedia: [Gamification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamification)

Comment: I think my favorite quote on the subject is from the SO blog: [**"It turns out that people will do _anything_ for fake internet points"**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/) even though the next sentence is "Just kidding."

Answer (score 0):

Definitely gamification, but maybe also a kind of filter for head hunters or a way to pimp your resume :)